# Django application on passenger shows empty home page

Tags: python, django, passenger, dreamhost

In my local environment, which is run by `python manage.py runserver`
I can visit normally the application home in my `http://localhost:8000`

On passenger, I can work with some endpoints of my system in the remote domain, but I cannot access `http://my.domain.com/` or `http://my.domain.com`. It shows a blank page, as in my local environment I can normally see the home.

I then created another endpoint to show my home, to check static files and so, like:
`http://localhost:8000/h`

In passenger **I can normally see** `http://my.domain.com/h` as my home page, but I cant really make it work to see the home page in the root of the domain (as in any other website): `http://my.domain.com`

In my url's I tried many, but no success.

My django project is in public folder. And this is the folder structure I have for passenger.

```
/path/to/project/public
/path/to/project/passenger_wsgi.py
/path/to/project/tmp/restart.txt
```

How can I make this home work in `http://my.domain.com`?

Welcome any help

Comment: post your `urls.py` please

Comment: there was an index.html in my project files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite clear.

As explained in the [Docs](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216385637-How-do-I-enable-Passenger-on-my-domain-),

> The "public" subdirectory
>   Passenger maps the directory named "public" to be the document root for your domain/subdomain.
>   If a static HTML file named "public/index.html" exists, it's then used as the response for requests for the root document (i.e., "/").
>   If you want your application to handle requests for the root document, then you must first remove "public/index.html" (if it exists).
>   By default, Ruby on Rails creates a static "public/index.html" file.

Wasted few hours of my time in this wtf.